# troubleshooting Cakephp auth component not allowing allowed actions

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

Sept 2 update:

This has become a very difficult puzzle to solve. Setting up a basic auth, which is all that I want, should involve very few steps. I have done many tests, adding and removing code, reviewing the cake manual, reading tutorials and going step by step through the cakePHP 1.3 application development cookbook by Mariano Iglesias - good book. http://goo.gl/93BGw

But the problem I'm still facing is that the app controller is the only place the 'allowed' actions work. In individual controllers the parent:beforeFilter doesn't get recognized and I'm redirected back to the users login page.

Any help with this is really appreciated. What I'm wondering is how I might debug this type of problem. Are there any other configuration settings I should look at, like 'prefix routing'?

=======================

Sept 1 update:

After a lot of testing what appears to be the issue is that the 'before:filter' in individual controllers isn't being recognized. Example in the post controller:

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow = array('edit'); 
}
```

Has anyone had this happen before? I've referred to the cakePHP manual as well as many online articles and tutorials and it doesn't make any sense to me. I've even tried to build a simple application with just the users and post controller and still, the before:filter settings in each controller aren't being recognized.

=======================
Original question.

I am using the Cakephp auth component to manage an admin section. This is using version 1.3.11

The problem I'm having is that even with allowed actions in each controller, I'm being redirected to the user login page.

Here is what's in the app controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

var $components  = array(
'Auth' => array(
'authorize' => 'controller'
),
'Session',
'RequestHandler'
);

public function isAuthorized() { 
return true; 
}

function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->authError = 'Please login to view that page ';
    $this->Auth->loginError =' The user name or password you entered did not work, please try again ' ; 
            $this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'); 
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'); 
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home');     
}
```

This is what's in the users controller:
    class UsersController extends AppController {

```
var $name = 'Users';

function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow = array('add');  
}
```

This is what's in the posts controller:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Posts';
var $components = array('Session','RequestHandler', 'Email');   

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow = array('edit'); 
}
```

What I do find is that after I've logged in I'm able to access the home page, as expected. Then when I go to the logout the session isn't entirely destroyed so I can go back to the 'admin' section.

I did try using $this-session('destroy'); in the logout action, but when I did the allowed actions didn't work again.

Does this make sense? Shouldn't allowed actions be independent of a current session?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Hm, can you add any details about your logout action?

Comment: Try setting the login and logout redirect and try again

$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout');        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');

Comment: Hi 8vius, I tried this and there was no difference to the problem. In my testing what I find is that if in the app_controller I allow all actions like this, $this->Auth->allow('*'); then all actions are authorized, but if I only authorize 'index' and then in the individual controllers I authorize other methods like this,      public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow = array('view', 'aboutUs' ); 
 }, they aren't recognized and I get redirected to the users login page. So the problem still is that the parent:beforeFilter in controllers isn't working. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not using requestAction in any of your elements or views, make sure that the actions called by requestAction are allowed too.... this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Rui, while this by itself didn't resolve the issue, what I also did was to remove all 'auth' references and then loaded them back into the controllers that required auth. That seems to allow auth and controller actions that could be excluded from auth to work. Still very strange and not what expect from a cake app. Thanks again for the input and help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For the one when you logout and I can still access admin section: the logout() should have `$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());` It should clear the Auth session data.

Here's what I suggest for the beforeFilter() in appcontroller:

> ```
> function beforeFilter(){
>    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
> }
> ```

and for the pages controller: `$this->Auth->allow('display', 'view');`

Comment: Careful, having isAuthorized() return true in the AppController does NOT make Auth useless. It just means that any authenticated user can access actions that are protected with the AuthComponent. And since he's set the Auth::$authorize property to 'controller', I believe he actually needs to have the isAuthorized() method returning true there. The isAuthorized() method is where you can put code that confirms whether an authenticated user is authorized to access a particular method. You can use this to set up multiple prefixes (admin, manager) and determine which a particular user can access.

Comment: Right. I was thinking about allow('*'). Sorry. I don't think he needs that for now, nevertheless. Because it always returns true.

Comment: Thanks Anh, this part I understand. What remains a mystery is why I'm always redirected to the users/login even though controllers likes 'pages' have the parent::beforeFilter(); for allowed actions. It doesn't make any sense that these authorized actions are ignored. I've tried everything I can think of, read through the cake manual, searched online, watched youtube tutorials...still nothing stands out. One thing is consistent, after I log in everything is accessible. Any advice on trouble shooting is appreciated. Thanks, Paul

Comment: Paul, i'm have the exact same problem you have.... i have added parent::beforeFilter(); $this->Auth->allow('gestao_acessibilidade'); to pages controller and it keeps redirecting to login.... when i try to access gestao_acessibilidade... i really don't know what to do too! :(